# Database not updating values, blank page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ok, here I go again. I asked a questions similar to this one, but the difference being here is that there is no form.

I am trying to verify a users account so I send a verification link to the users email address and when they click the link I need the database to update the is_active column in the database to 1 and wipe out the token for the URL.

Here is my php code that should execute when the user clicks on the link:

```
require("../config.php"); //connects to the database

$sql = "SELECT activation_expiration, is_active FROM users WHERE activation = :token";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":token", $_GET['token']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();

// Is the user active?
$is_active = $result['is_active'];

//Get Token Expiration Date
$tokenExpiration = $result['activation_expiration'];

// Get current DateTime
$now = new DateTime();
$currentDate = $now->format('Y-m-d h:i:s a') . "\n";

// This function will update the user to active
function updateActivation($dbHandler){
if($tokenExpiration > $currentDate) {
if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['token']) && !empty($_GET['token'])){

    $email = $_GET['email']; // Set email variable 
    $token = $_GET['token']; // Set token variable          

            $query_params = array(
                ':user' =>  $email,
                ':token' => $token,
                ':emptyToken' => '',
                ':active' => 1
            ); 

            $dbHandler->beginTransaction();
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET is_active = :active, activation_expiration = :emptytoken WHERE username = :user AND activation = :token";
            $stmt = $dbHandler->prepare($sql); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
            $dbHandler->commit(); 

            $account_verified = 'Account verified! Please log in.';
            $_SESSION['account_verified'] = $account_verified;

            header("Location: ../index.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to index.php");    

} else {
    $dbHandler->rollback();
}
} else {
header("Location: ../forgot-password/token-expired.php"); 
die("Redirecting to token-expired.php"); 
}
}

// This will run the function if the user is not active
if($is_active === 0){
try {
    updateActivation($db);
} catch (Exception $e){
    $error =  'The following error occured: <br/>'.$e->getMessage();
}   
}elseif($is_active === 1){
echo "You have already verified your account!";
}
```

I am getting no errors and the $_GET values are being stored in the variables, but for some reason it is not running the update command.

So, my question is do you see anything wrong in my code?
Did I miss something?
Overall, how do I get the update script working?

> EDIT: sample url `http://www.mystreetlife.com/my-home/admin/users/verify.php?email=email@gmail.com&token=8d0522b85c9c16c3dfy349d02324058b`

Comment: Can you show us an example of the URL that gets clicked? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Also, do some error checking in your database statements. Have you looked at the error log when the URL is visited? Is `$query_params` populated?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I added the error reporting and received this very long error: `Strict Standards: DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead on line 20` here is line 20 `$now = new DateTime();`

Comment: Also, here is an example of the URL: `http://www.mystreetlife.com/my-home/admin/users/verify.php?email=email@gmail.com&token=8d0522b85c9c16c3dfy349d02324058b

Comment: For the warning that you're getting you have to change/fix the setting in the php.ini and restart your server.

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry if this is a stupid question, but what do I need to change in my php.ini? I only have 5 lines in this file and none have anything to do with date/time.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right php.ini? If you do a page with `phpinfo();` in it you will see which php.ini the system is using.

Comment: I created a php.ini file and added this line: `date.timezone = "America/New_York"` when i look at `phpinfo();` i see the change, but still getting the error.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: It looks like I had to add it to the correct folder, but i am still getting a blank page when I click on the URL and back to no errors.

Comment: You're not printing out anything to the page. Is the database updated?

Comment: No, no changes have been made to the database.

Comment: And nothing in the error logs?

Comment: I don't know how to check the error logs. I am currently using a shared server and testing in a production environment. My hosting package is with 1and1.

Comment: You'll have to ask them how to access the error logs. It is probably through the dashboard.

Comment: I found a few things I could do to capture the errors, but still getting nothing.

Comment: I fear you'll have to go line-by-line, echoing out variable values until you find the problem. You also need add some error checking to the SQL statements to make sure you aren't missing anything there.

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard. How do I add error checking to the SQL statements?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so i finally got it to work.

I changed my function code to this:

```
// This function will update the user to active
function updateActivation($dbHandler){

if($GLOBALS['tokenExpiration'] > $GLOBALS['currentDate']) {

    $email = $_GET['email']; // Set email variable 
    $token = $_GET['token']; // Set token variable
    $emptyToken = ''; // Set variable to empty the activation token in the database
    $emptyExpiration = ''; // Set variable to empty the activation expiration token in the database
    $active = 1; // Set variable to update user to active in database

    try {
            $query = "UPDATE users SET is_active = :active, activation = :emptytoken, activation_expiration = :emptyexpiration WHERE username = :user AND activation = :token";
            $stmt = $dbHandler->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(":user", $email); 
            $stmt->bindParam(":token", $token); 
            $stmt->bindParam(":emptytoken", $emptyToken);
            $stmt->bindParam(":emptyexpiration", $emptyExpiration);
            $stmt->bindParam(":active", $active);
            $stmt->execute();

            header("Location: ../index.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to index.phpp"); 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '<strong>The following error occured:</strong> '.$e->getMessage();
    }           

} else {
    header("Location: ../forgot-password/token-expired.php"); 
    die("Redirecting to token-expired.php"); 
}
}
```

and then run the function with this:

```
// This will run the function if the user is not active
if ($is_active == 0) {
try {
    updateActivation($db);
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo '<strong>The following error occured:</strong> '.$e->getMessage();
}   
}
```